# @media doesnt set new margin

Tags: css, media

That's my basic style

```
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    background: url('imgs/logo.png');
    width: 739px;
    height: 195px;
    margin: -291px 0 0 133px;
    z-index: 5;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

And I want to change the `margin-left` to something else based on the media. For example width `100px` but it doesn't work.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ho1oqzu.png]

```
@media (min-width: 1440px) {

    .bc {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 1150px;
    }

    .content_table {
        width: 1150px;
    }

    #logo {
        position: absolute;
        background: url('imgs/logo.png');
        width: 739px;
        height: 195px;
        margin: -291px 0 0 233px;
        z-index: 5;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: it bugged idk how to fix it
edit: thx sw4

Comment: It the first rule (with the `133px`) before or after the `@media` block?

Comment: it's after the @media

Comment: Can you please add this in Fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of your comment the first rule (the one with the margin `133px`) is after the rule in the `@media` block.

As both have the same *selector* for the rule only the order in the css file matters.

Thats why the last rule (the one with the `133px`) always overwrites the one in the `@media` block.

You should place all rules that are not in a `@media` block at the beginning of your css file and add the `@media` blocks after those rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
    #logo {
    }
}
```

`min-width: 1440px` is a lot. are you sure you are not trying to check max-width?

Comment: if I make it max-width then the effect occurs when the resolution is smaller than 1440px. that's not what I want